# LinkedIn Signup: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset while connecting with LinkedIn

Tags: java-8, linkedin-api, java-7

**The Java code to connect LinkedIn Signup worked fine with Java 8 but is giving the below error which executing the same Java Code using Java 7**

```
I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Connection reset
Retrying connect
I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Connection reset
07:20:52,013 INFO  [org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient] (http--0.0.0.0-443-19) Retrying connect
I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Connection reset
07:20:52,020 INFO  [org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient] (http--0.0.0.0-443-19) Retrying connect
07:20:52,024 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-443-19) java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
07:20:52,027 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-443-19)      at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:197)
07:20:52,031 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-443-19)      at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
07:20:52,035 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-443-19)      at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
07:20:52,039 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-443-19)      at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
07:20:52,042 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-443-19)      at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:936)
07:20:52,046 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-443-19)      at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1324)
07:20:52,051 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-443-19)      at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1351)
07:20:52,055 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-443-19)      at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1335)
07:20:52,059 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-443-19)      at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:533)
07:20:52,064 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-443-19)      at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:401)
07:20:52,068 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-443-19)      at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:178)
07:20:52,074 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-443-19)      at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
07:20:52,079 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-443-19)      at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
07:20:52,084 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-443-19)      at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
07:20:52,089 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-443-19)      at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
07:20:52,094 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-443-19)      at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
07:20:52,098 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-443-19)      at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
```

Comment: This is the error. We have to know what caused it. Without the code/configuration that connects to LinkedIn, we are unable to help.

Comment: Wild guess, as I see SSL classes are involved in the errors: you can check at [SSL LAbs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) that LinkedIn only accepts TLS 1.2, and I believe it's not activated by default in Java 7.